# Navigating Demeter's realm - Does she even have one?

Tags: gods

So I am writing a story about someone who is tasked with escorting Persephone from her Mother (Demeter) to her Husband (Hades) and back again.  Hades is fairly straight forward - a quick google search can get me a map of the underworld as the ancient Greeks saw it, so the two would walk along Ancheron Shores, board the ferry ran by Charon to cross the river styx, and get snarled at Cerberus at the gates to his throneroom.

The issue is I can't find anything for Demeter, and I am drawing blanks for how I can represent her realm - or does she have a realm?  Would I just do generic nature stuff, or treat her realm lile it was Chantee's (Dnd's harvest goddess).

Thank you.

Comment: Hi user992286, welcome to Worldbuilding! I am afraid that your question is not ready for _building_ a world yet and you may benefit by asking it on [mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) stackexhange.

Answer (score 6):

**[Elysium.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium)**

(Greek: Ἠλύσιον πεδίον, Ēlýsion pedíon).

Regarded by many sects as separate from Hades, more the preserve of dead Demi-Gods and heroic mortals, it was:

> happy heroes for whom the grain-giving earth bears honey-sweet fruit
>   flourishing thrice a year.

- Hesiod.

> The good receive a life free from toil [...] where ocean breezes blow
>   around the island of the blessed, and flowers of gold are blazing,
>   some from splendid trees on land, while water nurtures others. With
>   these wreaths and garlands of flowers they entwine their hands.

- Pindar.

> ten thousand furlongs distant from Africa, and are called the Islands
>   of the Blest. They enjoy moderate rains at long intervals, and winds
>   which for the most part are soft and precipitate dews, so that the
>   islands not only have a rich soil which is excellent for plowing and
>   planting, but also produce a natural fruit that is plentiful and
>   wholesome enough to feed, without toil or trouble

- The historian Plutarch.

Demeter, as [Goddess of agriculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demeter#As_goddess_of_agriculture), well the setting described above seems to fit .

**In conclusion**:

The islands (plural - two of them apparently according to the text) which Plutarch speaks of - if chosen as her realm, would entail a sea voyage northward among the other greek islands where one might meet .. goodness knows what on the way, before landfall on the mainland and the final journey past Tartarus, thence to the underworld of Hades.

Answer (score 6):

In traditional Greek Mythology, Demeter was one of the 12 gods and goddesses who lived on [Mt Olympus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Olympus). So, there is an actual, real world place which served as her 'home'. The thing is, also according to Greek Mythology, that's not where she worked.

She spent a lot of time out in the fields, ensuring fertile crops for the peasants and the like. She was after all the Goddess of the harvest. This is why the Greeks said we have seasons; late Autumn to early Spring Persephone was with Hades and Demeter was sad. Late Spring to early Autumn Persephone was back with her Mother and the fields were fertile and the weather was good as a result.

I don't have Google Map directions between Mt Olympus and Hades, so I can't tell you exactly where the transition point between our world and the underworld occurs, but at least you now have an actual destination for the journey.

Comment: There we go: https://agreekadventure.com/gates-hades-underworld-greece/ . And just because something is worth overdoing: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mount+Olympus,+Litochoro,+Greece/Caves+of+Diros,+Pirgos+Dirou+230+62,+Greece/@38.4474578,20.0937161,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x135813c2bb740cbd:0xb99522688db8a6e9!2m2!1d22.3585552!2d40.0884128!1m5!1m1!1s0x1361f1cd456feb07:0x97770e8c84a20473!2m2!1d22.380639!2d36.6384385!3e0